# Limit width of category axis labels in amchart bar graph

Tags: amcharts

I am using amcharts and have a bar chart that has a series of labels on the horizontal axis for each bar. Some labels have multiple words and I want them to wrap after a fix width. Is there a way I can specify with width of all the labels or even better each individual labels on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`wrap`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#wrap_property) and [`maxWidth`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#maxWidth_property) on axis labels as documented in [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/wrapping-and-truncating-axis-labels/):

```
var label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
label.wrap = true;
label.maxWidth = 120;
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/NBWNdm)